# sqlalchemy one-to-many ORM update error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables: Eca_users and Eca_user_emails, one user can have many emails. I recive json with users and their emails. And I wont to load them into MS SQL database. Users can update their emails, so in this json I can get the same users with new (or changed) emails.
My code

```
# some import here
Base = declarative_base()

class Eca_users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'eca_users'
    sql_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    first_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(15))
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200))
    main_email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(200))
    user_emails = relationship("Eca_user_emails", backref=backref('eca_users'))

class Eca_user_emails(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_emails'
    sql_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    email_address = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    status = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    active = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    sql_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('eca_users.sql_id'))

def main()
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:pass/ECAusers?charset=utf8')
    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(bind = engine)
    session = Session()

    #then I get my json, parse it and...
    query = session.query(Eca_users).filter(Eca_users.first_id == str(user_id))
    if query.count() == 0:
        # not interesting now
    else:
        for exstUser in query:
            exstUser.name = name  #update user info
            exstUser.user_emails = [:] # empty old emails
            # creating new Email obj
            newEmail = Eca_user_emails(email_address = email_record['email'],
                                       status = email_record['status'],
                                       active = active_date)
            exstUser.user_emails.append(newEmail) # and I get error here because autoflush


    session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: ...
[SQL: 'UPDATE user_emails SET sql_user_id=%(sql_user_id)s WHERE user_emails.sql_id = %(user_emails_sql_id)s'] [parameters: {**'sql_user_id': None**, 'user_emails_sql_id': Decimal('1')}]

Can't find any idea why this sql_user_id is None :(

When I chek exstUser and newEmail objects in debugger - it looks like everething fine. I mean all the reference is OK. The session obj and it's dirty attribute looks also OK in the debugger (sql_user_id is set for Eca_user_emails obj).

And what is most strange for me - this code worked absolutely fine when it was without a main function, just all code after the classes declaration. But after I wrote main declaration and put all code here I started to get this error.
I am completely new to Python so maybe this is one of stupid mistakes...
Any ideas how to fix it  and what is the reason? Thanks for reading this :)

By the way: Python 3.4, sqlalchemy 1.0, SQL Server 2012

Comment: Where do you actually use `newEmail`?

Comment: Sorry, forget to paste this line:
`exstUser.user_emails.append(newEmail)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql_user_id` is `None` because by default SQLAlchemy clears out the foreign key when you delete a child object across a relationship, that is, when you clear `exstUser.user_emails` SQLAlchemy sets `sql_user_id` to None for all those instances. If you want SQLAlchemy to issue `DELETE`s for `Eca_user_emails` instances when they are detached from `Eca_users`, you need to add `delete-orphan` cascade option to the `user_emails` relationship. If you want SQLAlchemy to issue `DELETE`s for `Eca_user_emails` instances when a `Eca_users` instance is deleted, you need to add the `delete` cascade option to the `user_emails` relationship.

```
user_emails = relationship("Eca_user_emails", backref=backref('eca_users'), cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")
```

You can find more information about cascades in the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/cascades.html#delete)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I get it right: when I empty a child object(s) sqlalchemy tries to update it in DB and I get this error? Is it better solution not to detach child but instead update them?

Comment: @susumanin Well, it depends. Either is an okay choice. You just have to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: I hit the same problem with `cascade="all"` but I guess `delete-orphan` is excluded from `all`?  Difficult to understand. After I added `delete-orphan` adds, updates and deletes started working for me as expected.